# Adding pause to keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, keyframe, pause

I have this script letting 2 characters move around 360degrees each. Now i have to add a pause of 4 seconds each time both have turned 180degrees. I have tried it with percentages but that doesnt work well. Either the letters will spin too fast or way too slow or the pause is not long enough.

Anyone has a solution for my problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animation</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
      .letter{
          height: 80px;
          z-index: 99;
          position: absolute;
          margin-top: 100px
      }
      
      .letter1{
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: alternate;
      }
      
      .letter2{
          margin-left: 700px;
      }
      
      .letter3{
          margin-left: 780px;
      } 
      .letter4{
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      .letter5{
          margin-left: 940px;
      }
      .letter6{
          margin-left: 1020px;
      }
      
      .C {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 730px;
            animation: rotC 3s infinite linear;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
        }
      
      .P {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 730px;
            animation: rotP 3s infinite linear;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
            /*animation-delay: move 3s infinite;*/
        }
      
      
      @keyframes rotC {
             from {
                transform: rotate(0deg)
                           translate(-130px)
                           rotate(0deg);
            }
            to {
                transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(-130px) 
                           rotate(-360deg);
            }
        }
      
      @keyframes rotP {
             from {
                transform: rotate(0deg)
                           translate(130px)
                           rotate(0deg);
            }
            to {
                transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(130px) 
                           rotate(-360deg);
            }
        }


      
    
    </style>
  
   <div class="vid"><!-- prycto-->
   <img src="geknletters/P.png" alt="p" class="P letter">
   <img src="geknletters/R.png" alt="r" class="letter2 letter">
   <img src="geknletters/y.png" alt="y" class="letter3 letter">
       <img src="geknletters/C.png" alt="c" class="C letter">
   <img src="geknletters/T.png" alt="t" class="letter5 letter">
   <img src="geknletters/o.png" alt="o" class="letter6 letter">
    <video src="051476630-astronaut-doing-ballet-dance-m_H264HD1080.mov" style="position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top:0;
    left: 0;" >
    </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kind regards,
Jorn Barkhof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can't stop the animation when the animation started .

There is `animation-delay` but that delays the start of the animation, but after it's started it runs continuously.

**The solution will be Keyframes with No Changes.**

For more info please read this link.

https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/

### And the Answer to your question.

**First thing** that you will do is to make the **animation to be 14s**
since you will need a 4s stop and 3s animate .

 3s animate (180deg) + 4s stop (180deg) + 3s animate (360deg) + 4s stop (360deg) = 14s

```
animation: rotP 14s infinite linear;
animation: rotC 14s infinite linear;
```

After that you will need to **calculate the percentage of the animation.**

We will need to use to percentage since we will do the **keyframes with no changes**.

(3/14)*100 = **21.4%** (For 3s)  -- (4/14)*100 = **28.6%** (For 4s)

(21.4% = 3s) animation and (28.6% = 4s) stop time. For the 14s period of time.

then **initialize the percentage**

**0%** + 21.4% = **21.4%** [total time 3s] -- *since (21.4% = 3s) animation*

21.4% + 28.6% = **50%** [total time 7s] -- *since (28.6% = 4s) stop time*

50% + 21.4% = **71.4%** [total time 10s]

71.4% + 28.6% = **100%** [total time 14s]

```css
.letter{
          height: 80px;
          z-index: 99;
          position: absolute;
          margin-top: 100px
      }
      
      .letter1{
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: alternate;
      }
      
      .letter2{
          margin-left: 700px;
      }
      
      .letter3{
          margin-left: 780px;
      } 
      .letter4{
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      .letter5{
          margin-left: 940px;
      }
      .letter6{
          margin-left: 1020px;
      }
      
      .C {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 730px;
            animation: rotC 14s infinite linear;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
        }
      
      .P {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 730px;
            animation: rotP 14s infinite linear;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
            /*animation-delay: move 3s infinite;*/
        }
      
      
      @keyframes rotC {
             0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg)
                           translate(-130px)
                           rotate(0deg);
            }
        
            21.4% {
                transform: rotate(180deg)
                           translate(-130px)
                           rotate(-180deg);
            }
        
            50% {
                transform: rotate(180deg)
                           translate(-130px)
                           rotate(-180deg);
            }
            
            71.4% {
                transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(-130px)
                           rotate(-360deg);
            }
        
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(-130px) 
                           rotate(-360deg);
            }
        }
      
      @keyframes rotP {
             0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg)
                           translate(130px)
                           rotate(0deg);
            }
        
            21.4% {
                transform: rotate(180deg)
                           translate(130px)
                           rotate(-180deg);
            }
        
            50% {
                transform: rotate(180deg)
                           translate(130px)
                           rotate(-180deg);
            }
        
        
            71.4% {
                transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(130px)
                           rotate(-360deg);
            }
        
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(130px) 
                           rotate(-360deg);
            }
        }
```

```html
 <div class="vid"><!-- prycto-->
   <img src="geknletters/P.png" alt="p" class="P letter">
   <img src="geknletters/R.png" alt="r" class="letter2 letter">
   <img src="geknletters/y.png" alt="y" class="letter3 letter">
       <img src="geknletters/C.png" alt="c" class="C letter">
   <img src="geknletters/T.png" alt="t" class="letter5 letter">
   <img src="geknletters/o.png" alt="o" class="letter6 letter">
    <video src="051476630-astronaut-doing-ballet-dance-m_H264HD1080.mov" style="position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top:0;
    left: 0;" >
    </video>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly what i ment, Thank you alot sir!

Comment: No worries. happy to help.

Comment: also I have an article on medium about this.
[CSS Keyframe Animation with Pause between Keyframes](https://codeburst.io/css-keyframe-animation-with-pause-between-keyframes-50a3b3d14354)